# Windows 7 boot loop with Linux disk present

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, multi-boot

I recently installed Windows 7 Professional on a spare disk (SATA3 SSD) and intend to dual-boot it with Debian Unstable, my main OS. For this, I removed my Linux disk (SATA3 SSD as well) so I wouldn't accidentally damage the system.

However, now after all updates etc. of the Windows installation are finished and I reconnected the Linux disk, Windows won't boot any more. Instead, it enters a boot loop, first displaying a screen telling me that it wasn't able to boot successfully. Occasionally, instead of taking me back to that screen, it also starts the Linux disk or enters an unresponsive state with a blinking cursor instead. If I disconnect the Linux disk, Windows boots fine.

Additional details:

- I attempted dual-booting simply by choosing the appropriate disk in the UEFI boot menu.
- In the UEFI, the controller is set to AHCI.
- Windows installed itself to use GPT, Linux uses the MBR. (Thus, grub2 can't boot the Windows disk.)
- None of the options in the Windows boot menu (F8, which I'm only rarely able to reach) appear to do anything at all, they instead cause a loop as well. Even "boot log".
- I haven't found a useful option on the Windows DVD, either.
- During the Windows installation, I had set the controller to use IDE (pestered me about missing drivers otherwise).
- Windows drivers for my mainboard components are installed.
- I have an Asrock Z77 Pro4 with two SATA chipsets. I haven't yet experimented with those too much since I don't understand their purpose. I use the native (Intel) one.
- It doesn't seem to matter which disk is on port 0 and which is on port 1.
- I can mount the Windows partitions just fine under Linux.
- During the Windows failed boot, a screen saying "Windows is loading files..." appears, which I infer from Google is unusual.

It should be mentioned that I know very little about Windows, this is the first time in 15 years I have it on my computer outside a virtual machine.

Edit: Update: The drive gets recognized as a SCSI disk device under windows instead of an ATA device, which might point towards the problem itself.

Comment: i think if you install windows using IDE-mode instead of AHCI-mode you're stuck with IDE-mode.  set the controller back to IDE and try booting Windows again.  if it works, you'll need to reinstall Windows to use AHCI mode.  (Win10 installer may have the drivers you're missing, if that's an option.)

Comment: I should have mentioned it in the first place, this doesn't work. If I do so, the UEFI menu doesn't show the "Windows Boot Loader" option any more, and if I choose the disk itself, I get stuck with a blinking cursor as well. (But that seems to be a different one than the usual boot produces - the latter doesn't allow keyboard input, the IDE one lets me reboot the system with Ctrl + Alt + Delete.)

Also, I only have a Win 7 license and _really_ dislike the intrusive nature of later versions.

Comment: You don't need to reinstall windows to use AHCI. https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61869-ahci-enable-windows-7-vista.html

Comment: The first change it mentions (msahci\Start) was already set to 0, the other key didn't exist.